# Src-resolve: Cannot Resolve The Name 'Flowers' To A(n) 'type Definition' Component

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd-validation

cI have an XML file that I need to read and it looks similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flowers>
    <flower name="rose">
        <soilType>Podzolic</soilType>   
        <visualParameters>
            <stemColor>Green</stemColor>
            <leafColor>Red</leafColor>
            <averageSize>50</averageSize>
        </visualParameters>
    <growingTips>
            <LightType>photophilous</LightType>
            <temperature>38</temperature>
            <watering>1200</watering>
        </growingTips>
    <multiplying>bySeeds</multiplying>
    <origin>Belarus</origin>
        <description>Classic Choice</description>
    </flower>
</flowers>
```

At build time I am using `JAXB` to generate my classes for XSD(this xsd is modified by few columns). When I try to validate it, it complains

> Cannot Resolve The Name 'Flowers' To A(n) 'type Definition' Component.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="flowers" type="Flowers"></xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="flowers">
   <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="flower" type="flower" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
   </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>

   <xs:element name="flower" type="FlowerType"/>
 <xs:complexType name="flower">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="soilType" type="SoilType" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="visualParameters" type="VisualParameters" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="growingTips" type="growingTips" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="multiplyingType" type="multiplyingType" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="origin" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>


  <xs:complexType name="growingTips">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="temperature" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="watering" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="value" type="lightingType"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="VisualParameters">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="stemColor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="leafColor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="averageSize" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="multiplyingType">
    <xs:restriction base="SoilName"/>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="SoilType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="value" type="Soil" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="lightingType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="photophilous"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="unphotophilous"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="SoilName">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="byLeafs"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="byCutting"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="bySeeds"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="Soil">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="podzolic"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="dirt"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="sodPodzolic"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

How do I setup my schema to validate successfully the xml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the `flowers` element definition is the cause, it should probably read:

```
<xs:complexType name="flowers">
   <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="flower" type="flower" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
   </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: thank you. it's resolved the first problem. but now i had another. i am update the post

Comment: You have `Flowers` with capital `F` in `<xs:element name="flowers" type="Flowers">`, but `f` in type definition.

Comment: Also, this line seems out of place: `<xs:element name="flower" type="FlowerType"/>`

Comment: the validator says: The XML document is valid. thank you for your help !